# SharePoint Feature not visible

Tags: sharepoint

I deployed 4 features in a solution, 3 visible and 1 not, they all are web scoped. I can see the all features are in layout feature folders. Also when I do this,

```
Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope,DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName,Id
```

I see all 3 features then 1 ?

the feature is visible on my friend computer just not on mine, please helpo

Comment: If your feature is not visible by Get-SPFeature also then probably you need to check the features folder "15\Template\Features". If still you couldn't find your feature then something is wrong with the deployment. By the way first check with visual studio deploy instead of SharePoint add solution command. You can also verify this in your database :)

Comment: Manu add your comment as a answer pleazo i want to down vote it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your feature is not visible by Get-SPFeature also then probably you need to check the features folder "15\Template\Features". If still you couldn't find your feature then something is wrong with the deployment.

**Edit**

<strike>By the way first check with visual studio deploy instead of SharePoint add solution command. You can also verify this in your database :)</strike>

Never Touch database even for select queries...

***Retracting and redeploying from CA fixed the issue.*** Strange but worked...